# NOT IN with one condition in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I'd like to double-check this:

If you're using a WHERE clause with the NOT IN condition, and you only have one single criteria, do you have to leave that criteria in brackets?

So in the clause below if Y and Z were removed, would X have to remain in brackets (see the second `WHERE NOT IN CLAUSE` below).

```
WHERE LastEditedBy NOT IN ('X','Y','Z') 

WHERE LastEditedBy NOT IN ('X')
```

Comment: Keep the brackets, write future safe code (and also portable.)

Answer (score 6):

The syntax diagram [in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/IN-Condition.html) shows the parentheses as required, but it does work without them:

```
select * from dual where dummy not in 'Y';

DUMMY
-----
X
```

and

```
select * from dual where dummy in 'X';

DUMMY
-----
X
```

both return data.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=79d715dcd12297ca2621e4df9269331e)

Including the parentheses anyway doesn't really cost you anything, keeps you in line with the official syntax (and as @jarlh noted, relying on undocumented behaviour isn't wise), will perhaps be a bit less confusing for someone else looking at your code, and will make future maintenance slightly easier if you need to add more values to the list later.

Comment: Now I'm curious whether other database vendors support this.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - from db<>fiddle it doesn't look like MySQL, PostgresSQL or SQL Server do at least. Not sure about DB2 form the errors that gives. It's questionable whether Oracle really supports it, or will always allow it if they notice *8-)

Comment: I'd never build an application depending on such undocumented "feature".